# Shuffling keys and values in a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python

Given data as a list with dictionaries, how would I return a new list of dictionaries where the values from  the key 'color' become the new keys and the associated values from key 'id' becomes an element of a list for the new values? Example:

```
data = [{'id': 123, 'color': 'red'}, {'id': 242, 'color': 'blue'},{'id': 329, 'color': 'red'},]

return [{'red': [123, 329]}, {'blue': [242]}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defaultdict` for this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> ret = defaultdict(list)
>>> for d in data:
...     ret[d['color']].append(d['id'])
... 
>>> ret
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'red': [123, 329], 'blue': [242]})
```

I don't think you need to return a dict for each key, as keys are by definition unique in your case, but if you need them like that you can use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> [{key: value} for key, value in ret.items()]
[{'red': [123, 329]}, {'blue': [242]}]
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but you should define `ret` in your code: if OP tries running this as written it won't work.

Comment: @Draconis Yeah, forgot about that, fixed it